# What will return autofac if register types as following way?

Tags: c#, interface, autofac

I have a question about autofac. The code:

```
public interface IA
{
    void DoSmth();
}

public interface IB
{
    MyClassType SomeProperty { get; }
}

public class C : IA, IB
{
    public C (MyClassType value)
    { 
         SomeProperty = value;
    }
    void DoSmth()
    {
        //realization
    }
    MyClassType SomeProperty { get; }
}

builder.RegisterType<C>().As<IA>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<MyClassType>();
```

Will autofac initialize property from interface, which wasn't registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `someProperty` is a read-only property which is initialized by the constructor of `C`.

The value of the `someProperty` property will be injected using the constructor of `C`.

By the way, *Autofac* doesn't inject read/write properties by default. If you want properties injection, you will have to register the type using the `PropertiesAutoWired` method.

```
builder.RegisterType<C>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

See the documentation for more information : 
[Property and Method Injection](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html)